# How to use proxy with zillow api vai Python

Tags: python, proxy, zillow

I am trying to make request from `zillow api`. However, I want to use proxy.

```
import zillow
api = zillow.ValuationApi()

data = api.GetSearchResults(key, address, postal_code)
```

Is there any method to have my requests use my predefined proxy?

Thanks

Comment: It doesn't matter if you use a proxy or not, the Python interpreter would always use your system proxy settings.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can set the proxy using environment variables as below:

```
HTTP_PROXY="http://<proxy server>:<port>"
HTTPS_PROXY="http://<proxy server>:<port>"
```

You can read more about proxy in [python requests proxy settings](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#proxies) page

Comment: I have used proxy using requests:
r = requests.Session().get(url, params=maddress, proxies= proxy_handler.proxies)
Could you elaborate where to add these lines wrt to my codes? I don't see how to pass the HTTP_PROXY and HTTPS_PROXY to zillow api?

Comment: `api.GetSearchResults` is using different request so if you want add proxy settings for `api.GetSearchResults` then you can set the environment variables as above. The proxies which you have set are limited for `r` object.